# selecting options in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

### html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ENTER PRINCIPLE AMOUNT</td>
<td><input type="text" name="principle" size="7"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>ENTER RATE OF INTEREST</td>
<td><input type="text" name="rate" size="7"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ENTER TIME</td> 
<td>
<SELECT id ="date" name = "dd"></SELECT>
            <SELECT id ="month" name = "mm"></SELECT>
            <SELECT id ="year" name = "yyyy"></SELECT>
</td>       
</tr>
</table>
```

### js file

```
date_populate("date", "month", "year");  //to get dropdown list containing continuos values 
 i .e 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8......31 in date to select number of days.in month 1,2,3...12.and
 in year 1,2,3....
 //as i move the cursor over dropdown menu i need to get this values.
 function simple()
{
var p,r,n,i;
if(document.interest.principle.val=="")
{
alert("pleas enter principle value");
document.interest.principle.alert();
}
else if(document.interest.rate.val=="")
{
alert("pleas enter rate value");
document.interest.rate.blur();
}
 else if(document.interest.year.val=="")
 {
 alert("pleas enter year value");
 document.interest.year.prompt();
 }
 else
 {
 p=parseInt(document.interest.principle.value);
  r=parseInt(document.interest.rate.value);
 n=parseInt(document.interest.year.value);
 i=p*r*n/100;
 document.interest.answer.value="simple interest:"+i;
 }
  }
```

i need three dropdowns to select days ,month and year.As user selects these values in dropdown simple interest should be calculated automatically in simple interest textfield.    but in above code i am geting only dropdown with no values.

Comment: I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/ctpddn9o/) to help understand your problem. However I still have no idea what is supposed to happen! Maybe it'll help someone else.

Comment: Use a pencil and paper to figure out what you want to calculate first

Comment: I think OP wants, when you select an option, a text field to appear next to the list, to let user type the amount of years/months/days

Comment: @markpsmith i have updated my code,in this i am not geting a dropdown list as i move over the dropdown.

Comment: @charlietfl , i have updated my code,in this i am not geting a dropdown list as i move over the dropdown

Comment: You need to add `option` tags in your `select` tags

Answer (score 0):

See Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lyffxjx7/

```
$("select").on("change", function () {
    $("#amount").val(" " + $(this).val() + "s").show();
});
```

You will have to repeat this principle with multiple inputs

Comment: yes what u thought was right .now the entered values should be taken to calculate simple interest and display it. how to proceed further.

Comment: What calculation do you want to apply ? Did you try to modify the fiddle ?